# Code Sign Error: Distribution

Tags: iphone, xcode4, app-store

I am just trying to process application submission, I did following

1- Created 2 Certificate Requests , one for Development and One for Distribution
2- Generated Development and Distribution Ceretifcates from Portal.
3- Generated and Downloaded Provisioning Profiles From Portal

Configured Xcode 4 with following Settings

Debug - Dont Sign Code
Release - Sign With Developer Identity in Profile
Distribution - Iphone Distribution : XXXXXX

-

This application is working perfectly on device. but i am unable to generate a pacakge for distribution to app store, I am receiving this error

**Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'GA AS Distribution Profile' specifies the Application Identifier 'com.ispendwise.groceryassistant' which doesn't match the current setting 'DDBL26W4M6.com.ispendwise.groceryassistant'**

GA AS Distribution profile is using same product identifier i validated this in Organizer also.

Any Help Please

Answer (score 2):

Just as a preliminary check; when building for the app store, I assume you are using a Distribution Profile that is provisioned for 'App Store' builds and not 'Ad-hoc' builds; and use this correct Profile with your Distribution certificate.

Also, the Settings you put forth are a bit unclear. Did you choose 'Dont Code Sign'? Or did you choose to sign with a Developer certificate? (both of which would be wrong).

To put it in one line, you should be signing both the **project** and the **target** with your **Distribution Certificate** and choosing a Provisioning Profile which is provisioned for **App Store** releases, and not Ad-Hoc, and ensure the app identifier matches that of the *App-Store Provisioned Profile*.

As a further guideline; not to sound condescending; you should just look through the app store distribution steps on the Portal once more to make sure everything went well. There's a lot of steps involved and its easy to miss some small thing which'll screw the whole thing up, even for an experienced dev.

Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Cheers.